# ActiveRecord:: StatementInvalid: Mysql2:: Error: closed MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am trying to do bulk insert of 5 million records in MySQL but getting `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection` error.

I am using delayed job to do bulk insert of 5 millions records into the database.
For testing purpose I hit 5 HTTP request each containing request for bulk insertion of 1 million records into the database so total 5 million records will be inserted into the database. I am running 5 instances of delayed job to do bulk insertion.

Answer (score 0):

try `reconnect: true` in your database config file.

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining your suggestion and providing more details...